# Trying to set Vue Meta page title using string + variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I'm using Vue Meta as part of a blog application within a project using Nuxt JS 2.4.5

I'm having some trouble trying to set the title + a variable from `data ()` and I'm not sure what I'm missing

I've tried multiple attempts at getting it to work, moving code around, using `this` setting it manually, nothing seems to work...

```
<script>
import BlogsFromJson from '~/static/articles/blogs.json';

export default {
  head: {
    title: 'My Website: Blog: ' + this.myBlogTitle, // or something else
    meta: [
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Read the latest news and articles from Flex Repay UK.' }
    ]
  },
  data () {
    return {
      title: this.$route.params.title,
      blog: BlogsFromJson,
      myBlogTitle: 'some title'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried setting a variable within `data ()` and using it statically.

Doing this should give me `My Website: Blog: some title`

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use function instead of object for head. 
Change

```
head: {
  ...
},
```

to

```
head () {
  return {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining metaInfo as an object, define it as a function and access this as usual:

> Post.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{{ title }}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

your script

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'post',
    props: ['title'],
    data () {
      return {
        description: 'A blog post about some stuff'
      }
    },
    metaInfo () {
      return {
        title: this.title,
        meta: [
          { vmid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.description }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> PostContainer.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <post :title="title"></post>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Post from './Post.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'post-container',
    components: { Post },
    data () {
      return {
        title: 'Example blog post'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do: `title: 'Flex Repay UK: Blog' + this.blogTitle` - this is what I need for this project to work within `data ()`

Answer (score 0):

```
metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.pageTitle,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more than just code as an answer. Instead, an explanation of the code and a breakdown of why it answers the question is most beneficial.