# setting title in NuxtJS depeding on variable state in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm realtively new to vue and I try to learn by doing projects I have in mind. Currently I'm trying to solve the following szenario:

I want to change the page title depending on a status in my toggle switch.

For files I have the following:

- `pages/index.vue`
- `components/toggle.vue`

I manually set the page title in the `index.vue` like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({

  head() {
    return {
      title: ' old and default title',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: ' description goes here.'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

in my toggle.vue component I have the following:

```
<template>
  <label for="toggle_button">
  
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_button" v-model="checkedValue"> toggle switch:  
    <span v-if="isActive" class="toggle__label">On</span>
    <span v-if="!isActive" class="toggle__label">Off</span>


  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { currentState: false }
  },

  computed: {

    isActive() {
      console.log('called isActive');
      if(this.currentState === true)
        console.log('trigger set even newer title here.');

      return this.currentState;
    },

    checkedValue: {
      get() {
        return this.defaultState
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.currentState = newValue;
        
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I managed to do both things seperately, but I fail to combine those two actions. I was looking into mounted() to somehow trigger the head() function but it's causing me issues. if anyone is able to help and hint the right direction in which I need to look into, I'd be super thankful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to set Vue Meta page title using string + variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377977/trying-to-set-vue-meta-page-title-using-string-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, aparently working with Nuxt is somehow easier then I thought.

I can reset the title in every page and component, without sending some infos back. So, with this, in the `components/toggle.vue` file:

```
<script>
  head() {
    if(this.currentState === true)
    return {
      title: 'new title (toggled)'
    }    
  },
</script>
```